# Vertical Scroll settings effecting horizontal scrolling with Datatables

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am trying to create a datatable that has vertical but not horizontal scrolling. The create table statement I am using here as follows:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#order-attention-table').DataTable( {
        "bFilter": false,
        "scrollY": 300,
        "scrollX": false,
        "paging":   false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
    });
} );
```

Currently my columns are wider than the screen and this causes a horizontal scroll bar to appear even with "scrollX": false. The only way I can get the horizontal scrollbar to not appear is by removing the "scrollY": 300. When I remove the verticle scrolling property the horizontal scroll bar goes away.

So my question is two parts.

1. How to I force the columns to fit the screen?
2. How to I stop the horizontal scroll bar while still allowing vertical scrolling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **SOLUTION #1**

You can use [Responsive](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension if data in your columns don't fit into the page/container.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "searching": false,
   "scrollY": 300,
   "paging":   false,
   "ordering": false,
   "info":     false,        
   "responsive": true
});
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7ggssbz/) for code and demonstration.

> **SOLUTION #2**

You can disable automatic width calculation `autoWidth:false` and set minimal width with [`columnDefs.width`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) as shown below.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   "searching": false,
   "paging":   false,
   "ordering": false,
   "info":     false,
   "autoWidth": false,
   "columnDefs": [
       { "targets": "_all", "width": "1%" }
   ]        
});
```

Also you can add `compact` class to the table to reduce table width.

```
<table id="example" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n7ggssbz/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: I copied your code into my html doc exactly without any change. The horizontal scrollbar is still there and the columns are not responsive.

Comment: @user2725919, you need to include JS file for Responsive extension as well (`//cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.7/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js` as of now) or use [Download builder](http://datatables.net/download/index) to get a link that includes all necessary files.

Comment: Thanks Gyrocode, its almost working now... But the last column is still dropping off the screen, no scroll bar this time the last column just disappears. Any ideas on this? I really don't need the columns to be responsive I just need them to all appear on the page at 720px wide.

Comment: @user2725919, with Responsive extension columns that do not fit the container/page will be hidden and could be made visible by pressing `(+)` button. I have added alternative solution for you to try.

Answer (score 0):

after enabling scroll, put following CSS to disable horizontal scroll

```
.dataTables_scrollBody {
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just had this issue and was pulling my hair out to find a solution, turns out removing the right and left borders on my TABLE fixed it. The tiny 1 px on each side were causing the scrollbar to appear.

```
<table id="example" class="display sortable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
.sortable {
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
}
```