# DataTables - scrollX wont Go Away when scrollY enabled

Tags: datatables

Below is the code I am using, and [here](http://live.datatables.net/tumawuyi/1/edit) is a working example with dummy data.  When I enable `scrollY` and set `scrollX: false`, `scrollX` is not disabled!  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollY: 300,
    scrollX: false
  });
} );
```

Comment: None of this worked for me, I found a similar post with more ideas (that also didn't work) but I added an answer with what finally fixed it for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847344/vertical-scroll-settings-effecting-horizontal-scrolling-with-datatables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set table width

```
table {

       table-layout:fixed;
       width: 98% !important; 
}
```

And change your div table instead `nowrap` class apply `wrap` class

So you table div should be like this:

```
<table id="example" class="display wrap" width="100%">
```

Hope this help you Thanks !

Comment: is it possible to increase the size of the table beyond 100% (say 150%) while maintaining `table-layout:fixed`?  The change is not taking place when I increase `width` from 100% to 150%.  I would like the table to take up MORE space on the screen.  Do I need to update `width` for the `div` containing the table?

Comment: If you increase the width of the table you will get horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've had this problem for the same reason i did:
When scrollY is active but scrollX isn't, the scrollX bar is visible, but only move the tbody.
If that is indeed why, then the solution to the problem is simply to set scollX: true. Then the header and footer scolls along with the body.